# What is BluetoothTest process?

Tags: bluetooth, 4.1-jelly-bean, processes

I am on android jelly bean and I keep noticing this process called "BluetoothTest" and I don't know what it actually does. I tried searching online for it but only ended up with other people complaining that this process eats up battery power.

Anyone know exactly what this does?